# EnumWindows Pointer error

Tags: c++, enums

I'm getting a weird error trying to EnumWindows to a function inside a class. Here's my code

```
EnumWindows(&ConsoleDetector::EnumWindowsProc, NULL);

BOOL CALLBACK ConsoleDetector::EnumWindowsProc(HWND wnd, LPARAM lParam)
{
    char className[200];
    GetClassName(wnd, className, 200);
    if (strcmp(className, "ConsoleWindowClass"))
        m_result.push_back(wnd);
    return TRUE;
}
```

Here's the error im getting:

```
ConsoleDetector.cpp:30: error: cannot convert 'BOOL (ConsoleDetector::*)(HWND__*, LPARAM)' to 'BOOL (*)(HWND__*, LPARAM)' for argument '1' to 'BOOL EnumWindows(BOOL (*)(HWND__*, LPARAM), LPARAM)'
```

Using MingW.
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 3):

You are passing an instance method. You need to pass a plain function rather than a method bound to an instance.

It has to be declared like this:

```
BOOL CALLBACK EnumWindowsProc(HWND wnd, LPARAM lParam)
```

Pass the instance of the `ConsoleDetector` to the `lParam` parameter of `EnumWindows` and it will in turn be passed to your callback.

Like this:

```
BOOL CALLBACK EnumWindowsProc(HWND wnd, LPARAM lParam)
{
    ConsoleDetector cd = static_cast<ConsoleDetector*>(lParam);
    //do stuff with cd and wnd
}

ConsoleDetector *cd = ...
EnumWindows(EnumWindowsProc, static_cast<LPARAM>(cd));
```

Comment: I found a way around, I passed my vector as the LPARAM. Thanks for help tho.

Comment: That's equivalent to what I wrote above.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use the windows callback function with class member functions in c++. Only static class functions or non class functions are allowed.

How should the `EnumWindows` function kown the instance of a class? You can only supply a function pointer, not an instance pointer to `EnumWindows`